# What do you call the second word in the naming of sporting events, e.g. "basketball GAME," "wrestling MATCH," "track MEET"?

Tags: nouns, collective-nouns

I'm creating a database of sports. There's a column in this database where we store this second word. We're trying to think of a sensible name for this column. Ideas we've tossed around:

- competition type
- unit of play
- collective noun
- noun of assembly
- term of venery (this one's mostly a joke)

I'm still wondering if there's an "official" word for this.

Comment: Interesting question... a bit off topic, but I'm curious as to why you're creating that as a column. Wouldn't that just be more effort to normalize the data?

Comment: @Julia I'm sorry, I'm not really clear what you're asking

Comment: I'd call it a "word".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to theFreeDictionary, an [assemblage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/assemblage) is

> A collection of people or things; a gathering.

While it fits, you'd probably want something more like "assemblage designation" or "assemblage name".

Or just "classification" as the type of thing of the second word.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, one of these is called an 'event'...but, in the event you've considered that and rejected it as too broad, 'contest' will serve.

If you crave a term of venery, I'll suggest **brutality**, as in "a **brutality** of sports contests".

Comment: Hmm... I upvoted for "event," in particular "event name" seems like a good column-name for the OP, but "brutality of sports contests" is just too silly for me.

Comment: @sumelic, I favor the specificity of 'contest', especially seeing as the titular question overlooks 'event' rather conspicuously. 'Brutality' is facetious, as suggested not only by the OP's "term of venery (this one's mostly a joke)", but also the recent (last 500 years or so) history of terms of venery, during which period it has been more the 'game of venery' than otherwise. In that context, "a brutality of sports contests" is par for the course. See [Game Of Venery](http://articles.orlandosentinel.com/1991-02-03/entertainment/9102010106_1_venery-nouns-lipton).

Comment: Oh, that's true about the title... I'm confused now. Maybe he just didn't notice the word he used?

Comment: @sumelic, it seems unlikely to have escaped notice, considering there's a "we" ("we're trying", "we've tossed") involved. I'm wondering why the reason for rejecting 'event' (if that's what happened) is omitted from the question.

Comment: OP here, we haven't exactly rejected 'event', just trying to consider our options.  That said, 'event' _does_ have an existing meaning in this particular data set—there's a table called 'sports' with values like basketball, soccer, cycling, etc and then another table called 'events' with values like "Men's 100 meter dash," "Women's Freestyle Swim."  So 'event' would be a pretty confusing name in this context.